# How to customize the datagridview with textbox and button

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

Goal:
Create a customized datagridview that contain one button, one textbox and två regular texts:

```
Sex    Delete     Age       Country   
----------------------------------   
text   (Button)  (textbox)   text
```

Problem:

> Having problem to specify the button and textbox to the right column.

I tried improving the source code based on this link [link](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-button.htm).

The sourcecode below is not being completed yet.

```
    DataGridViewButtonColumn dgBtnCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();




    // Add columns to the DataGridView.
    dgridDisplayCart.ColumnCount = 5;
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Quantity";
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns[2].Name = "Delete";
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns["Delete"].HeaderText = "Delete";
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns["Delete"].Add = dgBtnCol;

    //dgridDisplayCart.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Delete";
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Price/QTY";
    dgridDisplayCart.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Sum";









    DataRow dr;

    foreach (var a in myICartRepository.GetAllProductFromCartList())
    {
        /*
        dr["Quantity"]
        dr["Name"]
        dr["Price/QTY"]
        dr["Sum"]
        */

        dgridDisplayCart.Rows.Add(new object[] { a._quantity, a._name, 23 , a._price, (a._quantity * a._price) });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did never add a button to a DataGridView, but I'm sure `DataGridViewColumn` has no member called `Add`, and if it had one, it would be a method, not a property.
 So doing `dgridDisplayCart.Columns["Delete"].Add = dgBtnCol;` is wrong.

I would say you should add your button diffrently, maybe by doing `DataGridViewColumn.Controls.Add(your_button_name);` or by doing `DataGridView.Controls.Add(your_button_name);`.

Maybe you should use `DataGridViewButtonColumn` class.
 Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: That's true.. I used DataGridViewButtonColumn class but it is still not enough in order to specify the button to the right column.